# What should I do with my mac's volume?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

I'm trying to increase the volume from the increase volume button, but this is what it's showing:
[image]

I also checked the 'Sound' menu in System Preferences, but in the outputs tab everything is perfectly fine. What should I do? No volume is playing on my Mac.

Comment: Try restarting your Mac. This often fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the icon you've uploaded… 
If you see output devices in 'System preferences > Sound > Output', try selecting again the build-in internal speakers.
[image]

If 'System preferences > Sound > Output' shows no output devices, try a reset of the nvram.

Reference:

- 'volume stuck on mute, cant untick the mute box in sound settings (macbook air)' https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8593873
- 'Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac' https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063
- 'iMacの音量表示が斜線になりiMacから音が出なくなった時に試したこと' https://www.chawanmushi.net/entry/2018_0602-imac-sound-setting/

Comment: Answers should be more just links, especially if the relevant part of the answer are only accessible through the links. If the linked page goes down your answer will loose any meaning. So please edit the relevant parts of your answer directly into your answer (and leave the links for reference).

Comment: Thanks, I hope by this edit, the important part of the answer is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a connected audio device/audio interface that has it's own volume control then you cannot control the volume of that device from your keyboard.